# PHP uninclude or reinclude file in interactive mode

Tags: php

I'm testing some database related functions in interactive mode.

The first thing I did is to include the testing file, let's say database.php

Then I can make change to the database by a function call.

The question is, when I make any changes to database.php, I have exit PHP interactive mode, re-enter, include the testing file again.

I'm seeking a way to reload the include file during the interactive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple method of doing this cause PHP is not built for this job, but there are some things you can take a look at as it might do the job for you. However this all depends on what is in your `database.php`.

Create a simple function like `reset` and use PHP's [runkit functions](http://www.php.net/runkit) to update your include.

If your `database.php` contains functions, you need to [remove](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php) the functions before including it again. If your file has a class defined in it you could try the [import](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-import.php) function and just call the function that does all this for you but in the end this is all manual labor and it might be simpler to look at other alternatives.

I for one use a auto refresh timer in my browser to refresh the page every # seconds. However I have two screens which makes using this method much easier.

Answer (score 0):

That is something you should never do. It will create double functions, which will create confusion in the PhP interpreter.

You should require files out of your scope, so they are globally available, That way you can reduce the server overhead (memory usage) and reuse the included class directly without requiring it again.

Or you could create an autoloader, which imports the file when needed. If it is already there, it will return the needed instance without the extra overhead. An autoloader keeps track of the already included or required files.

That said, with include or required, you could load files. Instead of required_once or include_once, they keep including files.

Comment: PHP wont allow you do create "double functions". Throws an error that its already defined.

Comment: Hence the phrase confusion in the interpreter.